# How to make vertical and horizontal center without stretching image with css?

Tags: html, css, sass, less, stretch

If I set width and height using css (width:100%; height:100%), image will be stretched, and It looks ugly.
How to Fill images without stretching? What is more, how to make vertical and horizontal center?

Comment: You need image as background or as <img /> html tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div class="fill"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fill {
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

Credits to the owner of the image
image source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee9ql.jpg

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bg"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/PLZJasi.jpg"></div>
```